# TextView not display in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've got an layout with textview with id="credit_wallet".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/md_brown_900"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/lay_include"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                layout="@layout/top_points_bar" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/credit_wallet"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/md_brown_700"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <com.justfashion.Logo
android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:text="Fashion Wallet"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/md_brown_700"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listearncredit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/AliceBlue"
        android:textColor="@color/AntiqueWhite"

        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@color/Aqua"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My JAVA:

http://pastebin.com/raw/bgf4njkT

It doesn't show the value in credit_wallet. What is wrong? Please help me guys!

Btw. when I add some sample text it is displaying but not the value.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: It could be a textColor issue. try setting your textColor accordingly

Comment: also why are you using android:layout_alignParentTop="true" for included layout and TextView. Doesn't seem to be the correct way to do it. It might cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It's shown, But textColor is white "same as background, in your case it's brown". try setting it!

Comment: Nope, don't watch on it, it's different colors, similar name only :)

Answer (score 0):

It loosks like your background is brown, and your `TextView textcolor` is also brown...
Try changing your `textColor` to white ans see if it's a textColor issue. Brown on brown => kind of invisible value...

Comment: Nope, don't watch on it, it's different colors, similar name only :)

Answer (score 0):

just check this line in your java code

```
creditWallet.setText(PreferenceConnector.readInteger(aiContext, PreferenceConnector.WALLETPOINTS,0)+"");
```

whether you are getting any text or not. Put a debug there